# How to pass query string parameters to the PHP binary?

Tags: php, http, parameters, cgi, query-string

I am developing a webserver that invokes the PHP binary (via CGI) to process a script.

Here's the problem:

The PHP script isn't picking up the command line parameters. For example, if the client requests `path/to/file.php?test=value`, the `$_GET` array is empty.

I have tried passing the parameters in an environment variable (`QUERY_STRING`), but they still don't show up.

How can I pass query string parameters to a PHP application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various SAPIs for PHP. One of them is cli SAPI which apparently is what you're using, cli SAPI wouldn't populate $_GET, $_POST ... because it's for command line scripting.

In your case you need PHP cgi SAPI. (e.g., You need to replace `php` with `php-cgi`[1] in your shebang)

[1] In most distribuitons it's called `php-cgi`, if you compile PHP yourself you need to enable cgi.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: when you dont have php-cgi but want to simulate calling php in a cgi context what do you do then?

Comment: To spell it out, you'd run `php-cgi file.php a=1 b=2`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about *command line* parameters or *$_GET* parameters? Those are not the same.

When using a webbrowser, `$_GET` is used. But if you're passing command line arguments like `/path/to/file.php arg1 arg2`, then you have to use `$argv` (and `$argc` contains the length of elements).

`$argv[0]` always contains the running file, in this example `/path/to/file.php`.
`$argv[1]` is `arg1` in this case and `$argv[2]` is `arg2`. So `$argc` contain 3.

Helpful resources:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [Don’t call me DOM » Testing CGI scripts with QUERY_STRING, in PHP](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2004/07/testing-php-pages-with-query_string/), you may have to use `parse_str` to parse environment variables passed via cli mode - example in Linux terminal:

```
$ QUERY_STRING="aa=bb&cc=dd" php -r 'parse_str(getenv("QUERY_STRING"),$_GET); print_r($_GET);'
Array
(
    [aa] => bb
    [cc] => dd
)
```

Comment: Can you add some information about the environment variables? E.g., their names (particular names or by convention. Possible name collisions. Etc.). Length restrictions (Linux, Windows, etc.). Etc. (***Without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

**-- Option 1: php-cgi --**

Use 'php-cgi' in place of 'php' to run your script. This is the simplest way as you won't need to specially modify your PHP code to work with it:

```
php-cgi -f /my/script/file.php a=1 b=2 c=3
```

**-- Option 2: if you have a web server --**

If the php file is on a web server you can use 'wget' on the command line:

```
wget 'http://localhost/my/script/file.php?a=1&b=2&c=3'
```

OR:

```
wget -q -O - "http://localhost/my/script/file.php?a=1&b=2&c=3"
```

**-- Accessing the variables in php --**

In both option 1 & 2 you access these parameters like this:

```
$a = $_GET["a"];
$b = $_GET["b"];
$c = $_GET["c"];
```