# Query string is preventing a Cron job from running

Tags: apache, cron

I've been running a **Cron** job successfully with the following command:

```
php -q www/download.php
```

However the job fails to run if I add a query string, like this:

```
php -q www/download.php?multiclient=true
```

I've tried, without success,  putting the file path of the command in single quotes like this:

```
php -q 'www/download.php?multiclient=true'
```

As far as I know putting query string in a **Cron** job is acceptable, it's just not working in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a query string like this.

In this case, the interpreter looks for the literal file "download.php?multiclient=true", it doesn't interpert the part after the question mark as query string.

A simple solution would be to change your cronjob to make a http request instead of trying to invoke the interperter directly, something like:

```
wget -qO - http://your.sever/download.php?multiclient=true
```

Or you can try to pass the parameters using environment variables, that's how parameters are passed when using GGI. I've not tried this, but you may need to use `php-cgi` instead of `php`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3848901/1350899) for some details.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. In the end I removed the query string and found another way around the issue. Your explanation made sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter like this

```
php <path to cron file>/cronfile.php param1 param2
```

and get parameter on cronfile.php

```
print_r($argv)
```